How to force FabricJS to not change images absolute urls to relative?
I am using FabricJS and have problem when getting data from canvas. Code is simple:
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
});

canvas.loadFromJSON(saved_data);

var canvas_data = canvas.toObject();

Variable saved_data contains canvas data with images which have absolute URLs. However when I get canvas data back using canvas.toObject() image URLs are relative. Since these images are from different domains, they are not found next time these data are loaded again from database.
I couldn't find any configuration option which would change this behaviour.
Thank you in advance for any help.
